# A problem with a generator that merges sequences

Tags: python

I'm studying the theme of generators in python and can't deal with one task.

The point is this: you need to implement a generator that takes 2 non-decline sequences, combines it into 1 non-decline and returns it.

I understood how to write it with a function, but I don't know how to implement it through "yield".

Here's the code for my function:

```
def merge_lists(lst1, lst2):
    res = []
    i1, i2 = 0, 0
    while i1 < len(lst1) and i2 < len(lst2):
        el1, el2 = lst1[i1], lst2[i2]
        res.append(el1)
        i1 += 1
        res.append(el2)
        i2 += 1
    res.extend(lst1[i1:])
    res.extend(lst2[i2:])
    return res
```

I will be glad to get help in writing code and explaining the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code / Algorithm:**

```
def merge_lists(lst1, lst2):
    i = j = 0
    while i < len(lst1) and j < len(lst2):
        if lst1[i] <= lst2[j]:
            yield lst1[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            yield lst2[j]
            j += 1

    while i < len(lst1):
        yield lst1[i]
        i += 1

    while j < len(lst2):
        yield lst2[j]
        j += 1
```

**Explanation:**

We first initialize variables `i`, `j` to zero which represent the indices within the lists `lst1` and `lst2` respectively.

In the first while loop we consequently checks the smaller element amongst `lst1` and `lst2` eg. if the smaller one is `lst1[i]` then we `yield` the element `lst1[i]` and increment the index `i` otherwise we `yield` the element `lst2[j]` and increment the index `j` and rest of the loop is self explanatory.

In the other while loops we check if there are any remaining elements inside `lst1` and `lst2`, and if there are then we `yield` those elements also.

**Example:**

```
lst1 = list(range(0, 10)) # lst1 is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
lst2 = list(range(10, 21)) # lst2 is [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20

for num in merge_lists(lst1, lst2): # -- loop through the generator
    print(num, end=" ") #--> use the results on demand
```

**Result:**

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 # --> combined non declining sequence
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
itertools.chain.from_iterable([range(10), range(20, 30)])
# Should get your work done. 
# Or, in your case
itertools.chain.from_iterable([lst1, lst2])
```

Please visit https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html for more useful generators.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [9,7,5,3]
b = [8,6,4,2]
def merger(l1,l2):
    i1=0
    i2=0
    while i1<len(l1) and i2<len(l2):
        if l1[i1]>l2[i2]:
            yield l1[i1] 
            i1+=1
        else:
            yield l2[i2]
            i2+=1
    while i1<len(l1):
        yield l1[i1]
        i1+=1
    while i2<len(l2):
        yield l2[i2]
        i2+=1
for x in merger(a,b):
        print(x)
```

Explanation: merger() is a generator function. Hence every value of x obtained on looping over merger() will return a value. It must be understood that in a generator, the function starts from the same point from which it was left in the last call, hence i1=0,i2=0 would be executed just once.